# How to make sum of each person individually

Tags: mysql

Hello i have a table of customers which these customers have earned money from our company on different times there record are like this:

```
ID     Amount Payable

1000    340.00
1001    223.00
1000    122.00
1000    344.00
1001    155.00
```

My current query is making sum of all table, but i want to have sum of each ID not all of them.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
     remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeID,
         remoteemployees.Bank,
         remoteemployees.BeneficiaryName,
         remoteemployees.AccountNumber,
         SUM(transactions.AmountPayable) As TotalPayment,
         transactions.RemoteEmployeeID

         FROM remoteemployees, transactions

    WHERE
         remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeID = transactions.RemoteEmployeeID
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use group by clause. Please follow this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) for more details and tutorial

```
SELECT 
 remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeID,
     remoteemployees.Bank,
     remoteemployees.BeneficiaryName,
     remoteemployees.AccountNumber,
     SUM(transactions.AmountPayable) As TotalPayment,
     transactions.RemoteEmployeeID

     FROM remoteemployees, transactions

WHERE 


     remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeID = transactions.RemoteEmployeeID
     group by remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeID
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
 remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeID,
     remoteemployees.Bank,
     remoteemployees.BeneficiaryName,
     remoteemployees.AccountNumber,
     SUM(transactions.AmountPayable) As TotalPayment,
     transactions.RemoteEmployeeID

     FROM remoteemployees, transactions

WHERE 


     remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeID = transactions.RemoteEmployeeID
     group by remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeID,
```

Comment: Y have you downvoted this? Can you specify the problem?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:-

```
SELECT remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeID,
       remoteemployees.Bank,
       remoteemployees.BeneficiaryName,
       remoteemployees.AccountNumber,
       SUM(transactions.AmountPayable) As TotalPayment,
       transactions.RemoteEmployeeID
FROM remoteemployees INNER JOIN transactions
ON remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeID = transactions.RemoteEmployeeID 
GROUP BY transactions.RemoteEmployeeID;
```